# how to convert an image/map into a GoogleMaps polygon?

Tags: image, google-maps, gis, polygon

If I want to use an image (map) as a "guide" to create a polygon for a GoogleMaps layer, can anyone give me a tip how to approach that best?

Would this be done best with a GIS software? i would prefer a desktop/offline tool over any online tools (Mac would be perfect, Windows also ok).

THANKS !

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible desktop applications that might help you:

- Merkaartor - http://merkaartor.be/
- Quantum GIS - http://www.qgis.org/

You could also give Google Earth a try if you are tracing something that is visible on a satellite map.